# Auto play em video iframe

Tags: html, iframe, vídeo, reprodutor-de-video

Estou tentando adiciona autoplay nessa Iframe mas não estou conseguindo, será que o servidor não aceita esse recurso?

```
 <iframe width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="https://player.r7.com/video/i/59ce6d36bc1f62ee48000cea?layout=wide252p&full=true" mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Sei que no youtube basta passar `autoplay=1` na URL. Você tentou isso?

Comment: esse video é do site R7 e não estou conseguindo

Comment: Deve haver algum parâmetro passado na URL que só os técnicos do R7 sabem qual é.

Comment: No site deles, o video está em auto player

Answer (score 1):

Testei varias formas de fazer, via html não é possível no R7. Então parti para o js que também não é possível, testei o seguinte codigo:

https://jsfiddle.net/92jcg94v/

Porém ele retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta bloqueado acesso via js, por tanto, acredito que não seja possível fazer isso neste video.

Comment: Parece que ele só da Autoplay no proprio site. no recurso iframe não vai

Comment: exato, é bloqueado a chamada de outro domínio.